# Date format in Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am just working on Bootstrap **datetimepicker**, and I am done that. A small problem is there, I tried to change the selected date format and failed. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
});
```

This is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/vishnur15/8tsCt/2/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

check this jsfiddle

<s>http://jsfiddle.net/8tsCt/4/</s> --not working due to reference link broken

latest version as per 2017

http://jsfiddle.net/8tsCt/166/

format must be

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
});
```

Comment: Does nothing. fiddle broken I think.

Comment: What if you want format like 15-12-2017 13:17? Your format gives monday-december-2017 13:17.

Comment: @FrenkyB it depend on user machine regional setting, if you want to have fixed format, try use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to play around with it or create a new question for others to help you

Comment: I've found out the answer in bootstrap-datetimepicker.js - formats are listed inside. In my case it was: dd.mm.yyyy HH:ii.

Answer (score 10):

Please use `data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"` inside the input tag.

```
<input data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss" type="text" />
```

See this. https://jsfiddle.net/h0jk6oq4/

Comment: Use `data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"` instead of `data-format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"`. This works

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:ii'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using boot strap then there is no need to update the jQuery function just do it like

```
<input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
```

Hope this will help